# Embedded Fragment interaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a fragment with 2 embedded fragments. 
I would like to have embedded fragment1 interact with embedded fragment2.
For example I have a button inside embedded fragment1, when I press on said button I would like it to update a TextView inside embedded fragment2.

Here's my main "parent" fragment

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment1"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my fragment1 class onCreateView method:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    val mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)
    val button = mainView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener {
         /* Update TextView inside Fragment2 */
    }

    return mainView
}
```

Here is my fragment2 class onCreateView method:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    val mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false)
    val textView = mainView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview)

    return mainView
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read on this:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

This is the standard way. Basically create the `Fragment1` Interface for the `Activity` to implement; assign a reference to `Activity` in Fragment as that interface; then find the other fragment from the Activity to call the fragment method for updating the textView.

Edit:
In the case of Fragments within fragments, you can implement the interface in the parent fragment and attach like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
  super.onAttach(context);
  try {
        callback = (SomeInterface) getParentFragment();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Parent fragment must implement SomeInterface");
    }

}
```

However, as mentioned in the article, this is the old way. The modern way is to communicate between a shared ViewModel.

Comment: This is the standard way for Activities with Fragments, not for Embedded fragments within fragments.

Comment: Updated answer.